# Function runs before of schedule angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i got a Angular components that in the init execute 2 funcions, one of them charge a array and the second one takes the values of thata array and execute a service.

The problem is that the second funcion execute before the first so the array is not charge and the second funcion returns error.

This is the code:

```
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
  ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getProducts();
            this.getLoans();
        }

getProducts() {
        this.clientService.getClientProducts(this.clientId).subscribe(
            (res) => {
                if (res.success) {
                    this.products = res.data;
                    console.log('Obtiene productos');
                    console.log(this.products);
                } 
            }
        );
    }


    getLoans() {
        console.log('Obtiene loans');
        console.log(this.products);
        this.products.forEach((element) => {
            if (element.id == '4') {
                this.clientService.getClientLoan(this.clientId).subscribe(
                    (res) => {
                        if (res.success) {
                            this.loans.push(res.data);
                        } else {
                            this.hasErrorOnLoans = true;
                        }
                    },
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

and the console log, can we see that the log that the first functions execute before:

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz4TY.png)

Sorry for my inglish! and thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: I would suggest to call the second method when the first method has received a response inside subscribe callback

Comment: You need to call getLoans inside getProducts subscription, and a little research on asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not synchronize the two asynchronous call. The simplest thing you can do is call the second one function when the first one get the data, in this way

```
getProducts() {
        this.clientService.getClientProducts(this.clientId).subscribe(
            (res) => {
                if (res.success) {
                    this.products = res.data;
                    this.getLoans();
                } 
            }
        );
    }
```

In this way when you call getLoans() function products array is filled.

Comment: Yes, solve this with the solution!. anyway i need read something about asynchronous progrraming

Comment: Yes, when you do an api call in angular 2, it is an asynchronous one. Anyway if my answer it was useful, please mark it like accepted answer or mark it as useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Hope below snippet helps*

```
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 ngOnInit(): void {
        getProducts().pipe(
        map(products => products.filter(p => p.id == '4')),
        tap(filteredProducts => {
          getLoans(filteredProducts)
        })
         ).subscribe();
    }

getProducts(): Observable<ClientProduct> {
      return this.clientService.getClientProducts(this.clientId);
}


getLoans(filteredProducts) {
    filteredProducts.forEach((element) => {
      this.clientService.getClientLoan(this.clientId).subscribe((res) => {
          if (res.success) {
              this.loans.push(res.data);
          } else {
              this.hasErrorOnLoans = true;
          }
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for a solution like below.

### Solution 1

```
async ngOnInit() {
  await this.firstFunction();
  await this.secondFunction();
}
```

### Solution 2

Just using the `switchMap` operator or such things of Observable.